# ¿Abrir el sitio al publico de forma gratuita en PHP?

Tags: script, video, paypal, pago-in-app

trabajo en una plataforma de video por streaming con el CMS llamado VideoFlix, soy nuevo en esto de PHP y espero contar con su apoyo para abrir el sitio a publico en general.

El sistema funciona de forma muy parecida a Netflix, te registras, pagas mediante Paypal y disfrutas contenido, sin embargo deseo eliminar la parte del pago de la ecuación de forma que solo te registres y listo a disfrutar ya que de momento re regalara el servicio a forma de prueba.

Encontré el archivo que se encarga del pago mediante PayPal deseo saber que puedo modificar para conseguir esto, ya intente de varias formas y ninguna funciona.

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

De verdad espero me ayuden y no solo me califiquen con -1 ya que lo hicieron antes y nunca me ayudaron.

Payments.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Payment extends CI_Controller {

    // constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    function paypal_payment($task = '')
    {
        if ($task == 'paypal_post')
        {
            $plan_id        =   $this->input->post('plan_id');
            $user_id        =   $this->session->userdata('user_id');

            $item_name      =   $this->db->get_where('plan', array('plan_id'=>$plan_id))->row()->name;
            $amount         =   $this->db->get_where('plan', array('plan_id'=>$plan_id))->row()->price;
            $custom         =   'plan_id='.$plan_id.'&user_id='.$user_id;
            $business       =   $this->db->get_where('settings',array('type'=>'paypal_merchant_email'))->row()->description;
            $notify_url     =   base_url() . 'index.php?payment/paypal_payment/paypal_ipn';
            $cancel_return  =   base_url() . 'index.php?payment/paypal_payment/paypal_cancel';
            $return         =   base_url() . 'index.php?payment/paypal_payment/paypal_success';

            $this->paypal->add_field('rm',              2);
            $this->paypal->add_field('no_note',         0);
            $this->paypal->add_field('item_name',       $item_name);
            $this->paypal->add_field('amount',          $amount);
            $this->paypal->add_field('custom',          $custom);
            $this->paypal->add_field('business',        $business);
            $this->paypal->add_field('notify_url',      $notify_url);
            $this->paypal->add_field('cancel_return',   $cancel_return);
            $this->paypal->add_field('return',          $return);


            $this->paypal->submit_paypal_post();
        }

        else if ($task == 'paypal_ipn')
        {
            if ($this->paypal->validate_ipn() == false) 
            {
                $ipn_response = '';
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                    $ipn_response .= "\n$key=$value";
                }

                $custom =   $_POST['custom'];
                parse_str($custom,$_MYVAR);
                $data['plan_id']            =   $_MYVAR['plan_id'];
                $data['user_id']            =   $_MYVAR['user_id'];

                $data['paid_amount']        =   $this->db->get_where('plan', array('plan_id'=>$_MYVAR['plan_id']))->row()->price;
                $data['payment_timestamp']  =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                $data['timestamp_from']     =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                $data['timestamp_to']       =   strtotime('+30 days', $data['timestamp_from']);
                $data['payment_method']     =   'paypal';
                $data['payment_details']    =   $ipn_response;
                $data['status']             =   1;

                $this->db->insert('subscription' , $data);
            }
        }

        else if ($task == 'paypal_cancel')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('payment_status', 'cancelled');
            redirect(base_url().'index.php?browse/youraccount' , 'refresh');
        }

        else if ($task == 'paypal_success')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('payment_status', 'success');
            redirect(base_url().'index.php?browse/youraccount' , 'refresh');
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: el último if tiene el flashdata y la url de redirección, probá borrar todo menos eso asi cada vez que pide hacer un pago lo marca como succes y redirecciona

Comment: Ya lo realice y si la pagina dice "Success" y todo pero como no registra nada en la base de datos sigue sin darle acceso a el servicio

Comment: `extends CI_Controller` da un pista de que es codeigniter, en la carpeta models debe haber uno o mas modelos de datos donde se crea el usuario y luego se verifica la suscripción, opción 1: ver si hay un `plan_id` que sea de prueba o gratis por xx días y modificar para que sean X años, poner ese `plan_id` como default; opción 2: crear un usuario pagarle la suscripción y ver que datos se ingresan en la db (el `plan_id` que se ve en el `get_where()` es un buen comienzo ) luego buscar y comentar los chequeos de fechas/donde verifica `timestamp_to` ponerle el año 2028.

Comment: [https://www.moviflix.ml/file.txt] En ese enlace puedes consultar el archivo de la carpeta models porque hice algunos cambios pero sigue sin funcionar, asi que lo puse tal cual como venia